# How to remove all proper subsets?

Tags: c#, hashset, subset

Given a list of sets...

```
var sets = new List<HashSet<int>>(numTags);
```

How can I remove all the sets that are a proper subset of another?

Is this the best way to do it?

```
for (int i = 0; i < sets.Count; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sets.Count; ++j)
    {
        if (i != j && sets[i].IsProperSubsetOf(sets[j]))
        {
            sets.RemoveAt(i--);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm decrementing `i` because I assume everything gets nudged down one after it gets removed so I have to check that slot again.

Comment: Instead of removing items from the collection while you're iterating over it, I would grab a collection of indexes to be removed.  Then, after iterating through, remove by index.  This is slightly less efficient but it's also less likely to cause unexpected side effects.

Comment: @Jim: Sounds reasonable, but we could probably prove whether or not this actually has side effects, and then stop worrying about it? Rather than side-stepping the issue. Either way, this, and Grozz's solution seem to work pretty well in practice. Pretty sure `RemoveAll` was built with that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

```
var toRemove = sets.Where(s => sets.Any(superset => s.IsProperSubsetOf(superset))).ToList();

foreach (var s in toRemove)
    sets.Remove(s);
```

You don't need `s != superset` check, cause no set is a proper subset of itself.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_subset#proper_subset

Comment: Better yet, use `RemoveAll`. `sets.RemoveAll(subset => sets.Any(superset => subset != superset && subset.IsSubsetOf(superset)));` Thanks!

Comment: No... I know that, but I changed my mind, I actually do want a regular old subset ;)